# How do I check if messages were successfully saved to Redis locally?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, redis

I have two servers running and they are successfully relaying messages to one another through redis (I believe, but I'm trying to verify locally).

I have a local Redis server running at `redis://localhost:6379` and through my live messaging app, I'm able to connect to a WebSocket.

I have two servers: one at port 1337 which connects to my db and the rest of my Node.js app and the Parse LiveQueryServer, running at port 1338.

Redis connection in the main Node app happens through this object fragment in the config when setting up a new `ParseServer` instance:

```
liveQuery: {
    classNames: ['GroupConvos', 'GroupMessages', 'GroupConvoMeta', 'convos', 'messages', '_User'],
    redisURL: "redis://localhost:6379"
  },
```

Parse Live Query server setup:

```
var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;

var port = process.env.PORT || 1338;
var httpServer = require('http').createServer(express());
httpServer.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('parse-server-example running on port ' + port + '.');
});

ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(httpServer, {
    appId: process.env.APPID,
    masterKey: process.env.MASTERKEY,
    serverURL: process.env.SERVERURL,
    javascriptKey: process.env.JSKEY,
    redisURL: "redis://localhost:6379",
    verbose: process.env.VERBOSE_KEY || false,
});
```

I am able to chat between users locally, which leads me to believe that the redis connection is working successfully.

Via `redis-cli`, how can I see messages that are stored in Redis? Is there something I should be looking for in my logs specifically?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, if you are using Redis' pub/sub (as I believe this is the only reasonable way to use Redis as a tool to communicate between servers) then you are not storing anything in Redis.

Comment: Oh interesting. Maybe that's where I was missing something in my understanding. That would make sense why when I run `keys *`, I get `(empty list or set)` but also explains how my setup works locally allowing my apps to live chat.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to list all the keys, use:

```
KEYS *
```

Never run that in a production environment. In production, you may use `SCAN`.

If you just want to track what commands are being sent to Redis, use:

```
MONITOR
```

Answer (score 0):

redis-cli has a number of functions for seeing what's stored in redis; though it depends mostly on the type of data that you're storing. You can use:

```
keys *
```

To list all of your keys, and then depending on the type of data, functions like

- plain keys: GET
- Hash: HGet
- Set: SMembers

https://redis.io/commands/get